# How to https a folder in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a website that has wordpress and SugarCRM installed for a same domain. I have made few pages in wordpress to be https.

Now, I wish to make CRM to also be forced https. Note that I do not want everything to be https. Just 2 pages in wordpress and entire directory containing CRM.

I already have:

```
http://mysite.com
http://mysite/blog
https://mysite.com/login
https://mysite.com/cart
```

Now how to transform `http://mysite/CRM` to `https://mysite.com/CRM`

Whole directory CRM and its subfolders must be encrypted. How to do it? The server is Apache.

Comment: Just curious. Why wouldn't you want to make everything to go over TLS?

Comment: Because it makes site unnecessarily slow. Some pages really don't need encryption.

Comment: Have you measured it? Because it just is not *slow* as you state.

Comment: Well that site is just for sake of reference. Did you actually visit that site. :P

Comment: No I have not. But I have multiple sites who are running on TLS. Saying TLS noticeably slows down your website is mostly FUD. More likely there are other bottlenecks. I.e. WP.

Comment: Furthermore, I am caching some of my pages. Therefore I don't want to encrypt them. That saves some bandwidth.

Comment: I fail to see how caching is effected, but ok

Comment: @PeeHaa http://stackoverflow.com/a/1211719/1331135

Comment: yeah great. That would mean you cannot login secure cookies.

Comment: All the pages that ask for login credentials are encrypted and others are not. Wouldn't that be enough to keep the users secure?

Comment: No. When you login a user you want to secure the session cookie (and possible other cookies) by setting [the secure flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on it. Meaning it will only be added over a secure connection.

Comment: @Chirag: That answer is [**absolutely incorrect**.  Browsers do cache SSL-delivered content.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/174348/201952)

Comment: Is there a way to checkout that on a particular page with https... browser is storing cache or not? I want to test on my site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this in .htaccess within the folder to be encrypted:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} SugarCRM
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/SugarCRM/$1 [R,L]
```