# IE7 not Caching CSS Image over SSL

Tags: css, ssl, image-caching

I'm using the [WebDevHelper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper) toolbar for Internet Explorer to troubleshoot HTTP requests/roundtrips on my **SSL** site and noticed that IE re-downloads my CSS :hover images **every** time they are triggered. This causes a huge amount of roundtrips.

How can I prevent this from happening?

**Edit:**  All static content is served with *cache-control: public*, so images, javascript etc. are cached in Firefox and Chrome. This problem is IE specific.

Comment: Are you certain that this only happens over SSL and does not occur over non-SSL pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are being delivered from a different hostname than your main page, then you're hitting the artifact described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/21/Internet-Explorer-May-Bypass-Cache-for-Cross-Domain-HTTPS-Content.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Serve static content via http, sure, but don't do separate images for :hover states. Proper css image sprites should be used. It's just good practice all around, via https or http. There are tons of resources available for creating sprites. Supposedly SpriteMe, [ http://spriteme.org/ ] is an attempt to automate css image sprite creation.

Comment: I can't serve static content via http in an https environment. That creates the nasty 'contains insecure content' warning.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to create some css sprites! You'll cut down on http requests across all browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are multiple issues according to other Stackoverflow posts.  FireFox 2.x also has this problem.  But FireFox 3.x doesn't.

[Will web browsers cache content over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https/174509#174509)

Also in Internet Explorer, you go to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > Security section > Do not save encrypted pages to disk. It appears to be unchecked by default in IE6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

Content served via SSL will not be cached for security reasons.  If you want something to be cached, serve it via HTTP.

Comment: That's not true as a blanket statement. Firefox caches correctly (I have cache-control:public on all static content), so do Chrome and Safari.

Comment: don't server http resources over an https page. You will get ugly errors that will freak out users.

Comment: Cannot serve HTTP with HTTPS with out getting a bunch of errors on the screen.

Comment: Alex: I did not know that.  What is the cache-control you're referring to?  Is that an http[s] header?

Comment: Yes "cache-control" is a header that tells the browser how to serve your page.

Comment: Yes cache-control is a response header directive. It tells downstream proxies and clients that caching is explicitly allowed/desired.

Comment: There's different caching headers, I wouldn't expect they're all supported consistently.  It sounds like you found one IE does not support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to the header for those type of static files.

```
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
```

I know this works with in IE to allow storage of cookies through framesets and stuff.  Not sure if it works with static files under HTTPS.

Comment: Tried it, still getting re-requests for all the images. Which is really nasty if you have a (off/on/hover) 3-image combination.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds weird...
try to put a url to something that isn't exists (404 error). after this, all the rest of the images will be cached.