# IE backbutton works just once (as if browser history has just one entry)

Tags: asp.net, browser, internet-explorer-8, browser-history

I'm trying to fix a browser history issue. A customer of ours has a ASP.Net intranet page running for a while now. A colleague made it. Recently they asked to fix the "Back button" we made on their page (the application).

It looks at the sitemap and when clicked loads the parent page. However, in some situations I have to use "javascript:history.go(-1)". All worked fine on our test systems but when we deployed it on their test server it started to malfunctioned. We noticed that their production environment has the same problem.

Apparently all their machines (running IE) can only go back one page in the browser history. This is not intentional. We had one of their IT staff trying some other browsers and OS's. Apparently the problem (so far) only occurs when using IE. All other browsers they tested were fine. On my development system this problem doesn't occur. Also when I let someone else look at the site the problem doesn't occur either.

I have checked what their browser history length is set to and its 20 days. I tried searching here on stackoverflow but the only relevant answers concerning browser history didn't help.
[How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-ja)

Also pushing the back button (the one in IE), it only works for just one page back. There is no way we can navigate more than one page back.

How can I fix this?

Server: W2k3 R2 SP2
Clients: XP I guess / IE 8 mostly

Comment: You need to be more specific with the client configurations, are they really XP and IE8? or could it be IE6?

Comment: They've tried on Win2k and IE6 and the problem remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very much like a local configuration problem within your customer site and therefore unlikely to be seen elsewhere, as you've proved yourself. What you need to discover is how this could be restricted and SO isn't the place for that. You might want to try posting on SuperUser for further assistance.