# How to clear History ,Cookies and cache for all major browsers ( Mozilla, Safari and Chrome) in C# .Net Windows Application?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)

Is there any code to clear all browser history , cookies and cache memory from major browser like Mozilla, Safari and chrome in C#. Net Windows Application ??

I just want to make a tool where any one can delete those things rather than manually delete .

How can i do that ?

Thank You

Comment: This isn't done easily and has been asked various times before. For example here: [How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)

Comment: You could use C# to silently install CCleaner and [then run it with various command line parameters](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters) from your application

Comment: This is not a duplicate of linked question. The linked question is about doing same thing using web programming(in client machine). This question talk about a method using windows programming.

Answer (score 0):

Find out where those browsers save those files, then use the `File` or `Directory` types from the `System.IO` namespace to delete\nullify them. e.g. Firefox saves them in:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

Comment: Firefox has so many versions , then can You ensure me that every version stores their cookies or History files in above location ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it either in .net or in javascript.Each browser saves its browser history in a different way and at a different location.And browsers store their history in their own files.