# Is it possible to stop a browser storing a URL in its history?

Tags: browser

When a user clicks to a page using a link on a previous page, is it possible for the target page to, on its own accord, remove its own URL from browser history (without significant modification of the page that actually has the link on it, unless, perhaps it were a simple HTML attribute or something)?

Obviously I should not be storing sensitive information in the URL, but there are some cases where I have to store some information in the URL, and, while it is not sensitive, it is still better for it to not be stored in history. (These URLs are completely not useful to the user if they were to show up in history.)

So is there a way for me, as a webapp developer, to keep these out of history, at least in some modern browsers? (Something such as HTTP headers, JavaScript or HTML, etc on the page that loaded as a result of the URL.)

(I'm not interested in techniques such as fetching pages with AJAX, iframes, etc, where the user does not actually navigate to said URL, but still manages to get content from it.)

Comment: +1 this is an interesting question. I couldn't come across any way to remove the current pages URL from the browsers history. You could always use [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) or something similar to modify the URL so the information in the URL isn't displayed, but this would have to be done after page loads, and the URL with the information would still exist in the browsers history.

Comment: What about a good old iframe, with pushState support to simulate "nice URLs" if really needed ?

Comment: @ray, It doesn't fulfill the requirement as nicely as I would like. Perhaps nothing really will.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Yeah, by the way, I think "nice" as an adjective will be inappropriate in any solution we could find :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible.

The browser history will store the URL. The best that can be done is either to prevent the URL from going into the back/forward buttons, or use *"techniques such as fetching pages with AJAX, iframes, etc, where the user does not actually navigate to said URL, but still manages to get content from it"*.

Comment: I have been searching for a wait to prevent the URL from going into the back/forward buttons. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: That would be either server-side with a `301` or `302` redirect, or using client-side JavaScript `location.replace`. For more advanced features look at `history.replaceState`.

Answer (score 5):

Using javascript, you could use `replace` method of `window.location` :

```js
window.location.replace(String url)
```

Check [the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.location) for more details

Comment: In Chrome & Firefox this still adds it to the browsers history, but doesn't add it to the session history. This method would prevent the "back button" from working in browsers from what I've tested. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @TrevorSenior interesting, never thought it would append to the browser history...

Answer (score 3):

In *some* circumstances, sending a `302 Found` response and redirecting to another page could work. If you need to hide query string parameters, you could set a session cookie with them on the initial, redirected response, then use them to serve the response on the real page. Just remember to clear the cookie when you serve the page.

But this is an entirely server-side way to do it, and while you can hide sensitive data, you'll still see *some* page on the domain in the history.