# How to clear back button history using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript (I'm using jQuery if that simplifies things), how can I clear the back button history?

I do **not** mean the entire browser history.

I mean the history in the tab back button.

Comment: tbh, I don't you think this should be possible. I hate websites that do this.

Comment: There is no method clear in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2196109/2600397

Comment: @Phil: I need to do this because pressing back after logging out redisplays the screen. Of course nothing is clickable or usable, but the browser cache thinks it's a good idea to redisplay the view from cache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear browsing history using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript)

Comment: @phil some websites do this for security such as after user logout to clear his data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot remove the entire back button history. All you can do is replace the last entry with the next page, using `window.location.replace('url');`