# Not allow storing URL in browser history

Tags: java, javascript, browser

I have a java application where the url gets changed for almost all the different pages and browser is storing them as browser history.

Is there any way out not to save the url in browser history? Any javascript snippet will help me.

Thanks in advance, Amit

Comment: You should try to do a [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), instead of changing URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Martin. But the framework has been developed long back and now its almost impossible to re-design the framework with SPA within short time.

Comment: Found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript) but unable to delete the browsing history. Is it completely impossible ?