# clear browser history of webapplication

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I am working on the project which is using spring 3. Currently, in this project when user logout from the application we can see the application's visited page's urls in the browser history. I want to delete these urls from history when user logout for some security purpose. How can I do that programically?

Comment: First, you probably need to distinguish between "Java" and "Javascript" ;)

Comment: We don't code for free, we help for free. Please do some research and come back with code in hand and we'll help you get through this! :)

Comment: When i search on this, i only got code to redirect using history.go(). but this is not what i need. Please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be adding this simple script in the beginning of the page you don't want the user to goback to.

```
<script language="javascript" >
history.go(-(history.length - 1)); /* undo user navigation (ex: IE Back Button) */
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion naveen. But is it possible to delete the urls from browser history completely?