# JavaScript change / remove item from browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an upcoming project to work on a site dealing with domestic violence and we want to hide the visiting of the site from the browser history (incase abusive partners check this).

The plan is prompt the user to enter private browsing / incognito mode on the first page in the site they visit, but what I can't figure out is how to remove the history for the first page they visit before the incognito mode is activated.

Ideally we could use JavaScript's history.replaceState() method to replace the history entry of the current page to a news website, but it does not allow URLs from a different domain to be entered (for security reasons).

Second idea was to delete the entry entirely from the browser history, but there does not appear to be any JS methods for this.

So I'm stuck for ideas. Do you have any?

Comment: For security reasons, this is completely impossible.

Comment: just use an alert or something to remind them to delete the browser history, this question has been asked before there is no api to give you access to someones system files

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page