# how browser history do not track web page url on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, history, browser-history

I am creating a page which will be shared on social platform, 
when user will click to it, it will run in phone/web browser and on load it will download a .apk file in phone or open a website in browser of laptop/desktop.

But **we don't want to keep this page in history of the browser**. How we can do this using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: I do not think what you are asking for is possible. The browser is the software used to view/download the payload you are presenting to your user and if a developer's script could access this info it would be very insecure, as an XSS attack could steal every visitor's history. As far as I know JS cannot be used to remove the history of visited sites from a brower without plug-ins and this answer supports that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064623/8382028

Comment: That 2013 answer is rather out of date.  I believe you can do this with [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method)  (or possible even just `location.replace()`) though I'm not familiar enough with it to attempt a full answer