# Remove multiple items from history through JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have the following flow:

HOME => DEVICES => ADD NEW => SELECT TYPE => PAIR

Users can of course go back at any time.  Now after pairing is complete I go to the DEVICES index page again.
When a user presses the back button on that page, it returns to PAIR (which I don't want), I want it to go to HOME.

I've looked at ReplaceState on the final step which changes the PAIR page by the HOME page before redirecting to DEVICES.  That way when the user presses back in the DEVICES page he/she comes back at the home page (great!), however when the user then presses BACK again he arrives at SELECT TYPE which I don't want.

How can I accomplish that when the PAIR is done, the ADD NEW, SELECT TYPE and PAIR page are removed from history?

*Side note: I'm using Turbolinks and Rails, although I believe the answer would be JS.*

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot delete from browser history. But you can prevent saving history by `location.replace` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820194/4486609) or do another mad thing like turning off back button at all, but...

if you have classic web app (not SPA) then you have some system to prevent user jump to abitrary step at your wizard, and if you have it, it is already solves such problem, isn't it?

Comment: Hi, not really, I can indeed influence the buttons visible on screen, but I can't influence the back button the user uses in the browser.

Comment: what about `data-turbolinks-action="replace"`?