# window.history remove history stack except for current url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

On landing on a particular page I want to clear window history so that the user can't go back.
Is there a way to empty the history stack keeping the current url intact?

Comment: just telling you a simple idea I don't know your requirement exactly but for this you can open that link or page in new tab..

Comment: @AdnanTariq basically in mobile web view once a user reaches a certain confirmation page I want to clear history so that when user click back he goes back to the app instead of the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to clear browsers history at the time of writing this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064623/4241624

If you can bump the user to a new window however it will start as page one with no history.

this can be accomplished with HTML

```
<a href="https://some.link/page" target=_blank>Click me</a>
```

or with javascript:

```
window.open("https://some.link/page");
```