# how to remove history for last page use PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

> I want to delete history for the last page that was opened by the user using PHP.

Comment: Could you please explain more? Any sample code or why do you need it?

Comment: What do you mean by history of the page?

Comment: Is it a browsing history, last viewed or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean browser history, the answer is simple. It's not possible without using js and additional browser extensions. See [related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript)