# How to clear browsers (Chrome) history using JavaScript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, browser-history

Is there any code to clear browser history  from chrome in C# or javascript??

I just want to make a tool where any one can delete those things rather than manually delete

How can i do that ?

Seven years ago, it said that is not possible, what about now? [How to clear browsing history using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript)

Comment: Have you seen the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript

Comment: _"Seven years ago, it said that is not possible, what about now?"_ - why would something that amounts to a security hole be possible now? If something could clear the history via JavaScript, I imagine it would also be able to read the history. Imagine going on a site like Facebook and they know every website you've visited recently. Wouldn't that be a step backwards security-wise? From C# you could probably clear the `History` SQLite database in your Chrome profile folder (`%localappdata%\GoogleChrome\User Dat\Default\History`).