# How to push and pop 2 consecutive back routes

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to push a route and pop 2 previous routes from the stack. I understand there is a replace but I am trying pop the previous route too.

when I push page 5 I want the stack to look like this

pretend the stack look something like this. and the right is the stack I am trying to achieve

[image]

how can i achieve that with react navigation.

Comment: Please may you explain what you mean? Maybe you can show some code as a [mcve]?

Comment: I made some edits, hope it makes sense @evolutionxbox

Comment: We cannot help with code we cannot see. Please share yours

Comment: fam, the code is what I am asking for. I mimicked what the stack looks like and what I am trying to achieve after a route push. it makes alot sense if you take another look@evolutionxbox

Comment: How I understand your problem is, after 1-2-3-4 when u want to push 5, its back press should be 2? removing 3-4?

Comment: Sadly, there isn't a popState method in the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

Comment: exactly, push 5 then remove 3 and 4 from the stack so that when back press it goes to 2 @AkshayShenoy

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820194/989920 help?

Comment: If you're on page 4, and you hit back, do you want to go to page 3 or 2?

Comment: page 3 ofcourse, I think I am going to hack it by replacing same route and intercepting back action @Abe