# how to reset browser's history stack by navigating to new URL(ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, html5-history

I have a scenario.
I want to reset the browser history stack, when a user logs in.

this is stack now

```
index->login->dashboard
```

As soon as the user logs in, I want the stack to just contain `/dashboard`.

I have tried

```
window.location.replace('/dashboard');
```

This replaces the the current screen ('/login') and pushes '/dashboard'.

stack will go from this

```
index->login->dashboard
```

to this

```
index -> dashboard
```

I want dashboard to be the initial page after login.

I tried using `useNavigate()` hook.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('dashboard', {replace:true});
```

this does the same as the above case, it only replaces the current screen to the new screen, other remaining screens in the history remains.

I have also tried

```
window.history.replaceState({}, undefined, '/dashboard');
```

this only replaces the url and does not navigate to `/dashboard`.

Any help to how I can make `dashboard` to the initial screen after login is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820194/15288641