# URL that don't save in address bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a written script for this that if you have a link URL and someone visit it, it will not save to users browser history? Or is this impossible?

Any suggestion or opinion about this?

Note: To moderators, let me know please if this is ok, or else i will delete this.

Topic Closed: Ok, i figured out that this is not possible. 
"There is no clear method for the history object. The browser history belongs to the user, you can't remove anything from it."

NB: Thank you to all your feedbacks! I appreciate it.

Comment: This is okay, its a really good question though..

Comment: I think this is possible.to look for your domain in the browser history with a php script, then if it equals to over 1 it will delete it.. then this process will be when the visitor leave and visit the website in each file...

Comment: Directly, I'm pretty sure it's impossible. Indirectly, you could load the page through a proxy (or an `iframe` if the URL doesn't block access).

Comment: messing wit hthe user like this is never a good idea

Comment: If the user wants no “permanent record” of them visiting your site, then they should use private browsing mode. As for doing this “from the outside”, you hiding it from the visitors themselves – I can’t possibly imagine a single none-shady application for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Its not possible to clear user history without plugins . And also it
>   not the issue at developers perspective , its the burden of the user
>   to clear his history.

The same applies to editing or altering the information stored as well.

For information refer [How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)