# Make site not appear in history (through code, not user)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a website for people who need help (getting abused and stuff).
There is an 'escape' button on the site to switch to another site if someone wants to hide what they were looking for. But the visited page is still in the history of the browser.

Is there any way to make the site remove itself from browser history?
Or does the user need to activate 'incognito' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to clear user history without plugins.

For information refer to [How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)

Answer (score 1):

[location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) SHOULD have done this

> The Location.replace() method replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in session History, meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to it.

try

[This test](http://plungjan.name/SO/historytest.html)

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.replace('https://safe.site.com')">Leave</button>
```

which will replace CURRENT page - so your site needs to be a single page application (SPA) OR every click on the page needs to do location replace too

But yes, suggest incognito

Comment: Both appear under history for me.  Tested on Firefox 74.

Comment: Hmm, they did not use to

Comment: This does work but in order for it to fully work you need to redirect the user to a different `website` otherwise the last page will still get stored in `history`

Comment: @midrizi I do that

Comment: ***it does work but if the user closes the tab themselves or chrome crashes it will still get stored in history***

Comment: I also believe that this only helps with hiding the last record, any interaction on the website will create a new history record

Comment: Not if it is a SPA as I mentioned

Comment: @Nyx no if you have this in every page and you keep clicking some button it will hide all of them and keep the last one which the last one can be some other site like `google.com`

Comment: It isn't a single-page.
I'm going to try to detect icognito mode, and if not, I will show a popup.

Comment: If you navigate using `<a href="pagex.html" onclick="location.replace(this.href)">` then there will be only one URL that you can also replace on "leave"

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this.  You have no control over browser history.

It's possible (under Firefox anyway) to delete history using `history.deleteAll()`
but that requires an extension to be added (documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteAll). Which probably doesn't help.