# Is it possible to create a button to delete an hour old web history?

Tags: browser-history, privacy

I would like to offer the possibility to delete the last hour web history of my users (in order to protect people who used the website but don't have technical skills) or at minimum the url of the website and the referer (google search, social media link, etc.)

Is it possible with a html/js button which would interact with history like some extension ( https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteUrl ) ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Browsers generally do this themselves. Why would you need to implement anything?

Answer (score 0):

`Clear-Site-Data` is a header, implemented to different degrees by different browsers, to indicate to the browser that you'd like the browser to clear cookies, caches and other kinds of storage for your site. This can be a useful security practice for your site -- to clear any sign that the user has logged in, or to make sure that no one who uses the device later will be able to access that user's account.

While I can see important and legitimate use cases for it, it isn't possible to force or prompt the browser to delete the browsing history, even just for your site. You can see how there might be security issues with that, like an attacker clearing evidence of their malicious site from the user's device, or just annoying websites that hide themselves from history and so the user can't see where they were. See these other questions that have also longed for this capability:

- [How to clear browsing history using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript)
- [How to clear browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) history using JavaScript or Java except from browser itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j)

You might consider exploring the [`History.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) method and other parts of the History API. That won't let you delete URLs and referrers in general, but it can be used to modify the URL of the current page in the history. So if a user arrives on your site visiting a page about something particularly sensitive or revealing, you might be able to modify the current history so that their browser only records that the user visited your domain, and not that particular page.