# How do I implement a login-screen in GWT?

Tags: java, authentication, gwt

I'm writing a small GWT front-end for a backend app and I was wondering about the best security model for GWT apps?

I was thinking of implementing an RPC method that receives an MD5 of a user password from the client webpage, then passing back a session ID to the client page (or a failcode). All subsequent calls would simply use the session ID and the server would keep a track that the IP address for the session ID is the same IP address that created the session ID?

Is this the standard mechanism for (non-ssl) authentication for GWT applications?

If not, can anyone suggest alternative solutions?

Thanks,

Comment: This seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974100/question-on-gwt-cookies-and-webpage-directing A quick search on SO reveals some other related questions - do your research before asking.

Comment: Do not send the MD5 of the user password to the client.

Comment: What do I do instead of sending the MD5 of the password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) by google gives a good overview of the security and tasks associated with logging in users.  The link on that page to [Security for GWT Applications](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/web/security-for-gwt-applications?pli=1) also addresses several common gotchas specifically associated with GWT.

Comment: my answer adds zero extra information and its almost same as yours, however, that said, you got there first :) lemme delete mine