# GWT: Storing Session ID in cookie, and then what?

Tags: session, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm currently making a site using GWT, being hosted on AppEngine. I'm making it with my own logins that I'm making (I know Google provides something with GWT, but I need my own login system), and I've been trying to figure out sessions for quite a while now. I've found a few tutorials, and one of the sites that I was reading is http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ

There is a section there on "How to Remember Logins". I know how to get the session ID and store it on the client in a cookie through an RPC call. What I don't understand is, eventually after a day or so, the user comes back and I'm supposed to get the session ID from the cookie and send it back to the server. What am I supposed to do on the server in order to securely evaluate if session ID is still legal, and pull up all the necessary information about the user?

Additional questions:
1. What would make the session ID change?
2. What if the user was on a laptop, and the user went somewhere else. Would he still be able to be securely logged back in without having to type in his login and password again?

Thanks!

~Scott

Answer (score 8):

Similar question: [**question on GWT, Cookies and webpage directing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974100/question-on-gwt-cookies-and-webpage-directing/2976062#2976062).
One important thing you should remember: don't rely on cookies alone - transfer the session ID/token in the payload of the request too and compare it with the cookie value on the server side. This will prevent XSRF attacks. *That's* the sort of thing you should be worried about.

The policy on how to deal with session IDs depends on how seriously you take security in your application and what type of application is it. For example, you can login with the same token on GMail from different IPs - I presume they allowed this because it's common that the user's IP changes over sessions. They did however add a feature that allows you to see from which IPs the user logged in recently. And don't forget about users with dynamic IPs (quite a large number) - if you keep track of tokens and IPs you will basically disallow those users to be kept logged in between sessions.

> What am I supposed to do on the server
>   in order to securely evaluate if
>   session ID is still legal, and pull up
>   all the necessary information about
>   the user?

You should keep track of the session IDs/login pairs in your DB.

> What would make the session ID change?

Either it expires or the user tries to log in with a token that is not bound to their IP. You could add your own rules too - like the number of logins, etc. For additional security, you can generate a new session ID/token on every new login/session (the user authenticates with the old token, the server checks that it's valid and sends back the user the new token he/she should use from now on).

Answer (score 1):

To remember logins you need to securely generate a unique session id.  Normally, this is placed in a cookie.  I would recommend using a framework that does session cookies for you.  Getting it wrong can leave your site wide open to abuse.  Things to consider include:

- Do you need to worry about cookie stealing.  The user's IP address should be encoded in the session id, or linked to the session id.  Check the IP address on every page access.
- Ensure your logins are on encrypted sessions.  Otherwise, you expose credentials in plaintext on the network.
- How long should sessions last.  They should time out after a fixed time limit.  This can be hours or days long.
- Remember me should be different functionality on a different cookie.  It needs to contain something that can be used to indentify the user.  Depending on your security requirments it may need to be an encrypted value.  This cookie can have a longer timeout.

Answers to your additional questions are.

1. Nothing on the client side is likely to change the session id.  The session id should be regenerated every login.
2. Depending on how secure the session id is, they may have to login.  Secure session cookies often encode the IP address to prevent cookie stealing.  If so, the laptop user would need to login again.