# GWT client not receiving IncompatibleRemoteServiceException when serialization policy changes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, exception

When the new version of app is deployed with changes to the model 
classes (for example adding/removing fields ). 
Client who has old version running gets 
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException with the RPC 
made with the  old client code and this is expected behavior. 
As a result we expect to see  IncompatibleRemoteServiceException on the client side. 
However we get StatusCodeException.

StatusCodeException is 500 error and we can't customize the client 
side behavior easily (we don't want to assume every 
StatusCodeException  or 500 error is a new version) .  What could we 
be doing wrong here?

Note: On the server side (log) we get SerializationExcepion obviously since the serialization policy from the old client is no longer valid with the new server. So Why not throwing IncompatibleRemoteServiceException?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution facing that issue:

First extend `RemoteServiceServlet` (all your service servlets will extend from this new class, remember this is server code). This is the relevant code in there:

```
@Override
protected SerializationPolicy doGetSerializationPolicy(
        HttpServletRequest request, String moduleBaseURL, String strongName) {
    SerializationPolicy sp = super.doGetSerializationPolicy(request,
                                   moduleBaseURL, strongName);
    if(sp == null) { //no policy found, probably wrong client version
        throw new InvalidPolicyException();
    }
    return sp;
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void doUnexpectedFailure(Throwable e) {
    if(e instanceof InvalidPolicyException) { 
        sendError(); //send message to reload client (wrong client version)
        return; //that's it
    }
    super.doUnexpectedFailure(e);
}
```

The private method `sendError()` is basically a customized copy from GWT 500 error code (sorry for the ugly Google indentation)

```
private void sendError() {
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = getThreadLocalResponse();
    try {
          response.setContentType("text/plain");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
          try {
            response.getOutputStream().write("wrong client version".getBytes("UTF-8"));
          } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // Handle the (unexpected) case where getWriter() was previously used
            response.getWriter().write("wrong client version");
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          servletContext.log(
              "sendError failed while sending the previous custom failure to the client", ex);
        }
}
```

I used `HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT` (409) but you can probably use a clever error code. The message written is not really important.

Then in your custom `RpcRequestBuilder` (this is the client code)

```
public class CustomRequestBuilder extends RpcRequestBuilder {

 private class RequestCallbackWrapper implements RequestCallback {

        private RequestCallback callback;

        RequestCallbackWrapper(RequestCallback aCallback) {
            this.callback = aCallback;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            if(response.getStatusCode() == 409) { //wrong client version
                Navigator.closeEveryPopUp();
                Navigator.showUncloseablePopUp("Login again!", 
                                new ClickHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        //reload your $#%^ client!!!
                        Window.Location.reload();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //(...)irrelevant security code here(...)
                callback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            callback.onError(request, exception);
        }

 }

 @Override
 protected void doFinish(RequestBuilder rb) {
    //(...)more irrelevant security code here(...)
    super.doFinish(rb);
    rb.setCallback(new RequestCallbackWrapper(rb.getCallback()));
 }
}
```

We use multiple popups, that's one reason for the Navigator class; of course use your own style there to warn the user.

**EDIT**: What's going on here?

Until GWT 1.3.3 `IsSerializable` was the only interface available to mark a class as GWT RPC serializabled. The next version accepted Java standard `Serializable` interface for the same purpose, but adding the requirement of a security policy for objects implementing this interface. By default GWT generate a policy for each compilation with a unique hash name. An old client trying to transfer object marked as `Serializable` will throw at server side a serialization policy exception that will be received at client side as a generic runtime error. `IsSerializable` allows the old clients to still use the new services as long as the signature remains the same. This means that **an alternate solution for this question is to mark every object going thru GWT RPC as `IsSerializable`**. But if for some reason you need your objects not to be referenced to a GWT interface, this is a nice solution for old clients connections.

Check [GWT's guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/FAQ_Server#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable) for more details regarding the 1.3.3 fallback.

Comment: While this probably isn't a problem in the newer versions of GWT (ie. 2.5.1), it is useful to note that you can't test the functionality simply by throwing an IncompatibleRemoteServiceException from your service method, as GWT will wrap it in a StatusCodeException. However, if you test it by actually running a service that's incompatible with your client, you'll see the IncompatibleRemoteServiceException come through.