# How to tell browser to cache all the static content with Apache web server?

Tags: php, apache, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ideal HTTP cache control headers for different types of resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970938/ideal-http-cache-control-headers-for-different-types-of-resources)

we have a large project with number of static content serverd in terms of js,css,html images etc. The project is running on apache server and is a php based project. How can i ensure that my static content is served from the browser cache after the first load happens and users dont get a delayed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the .htaccess file here: http://html5boilerplate.com/. Not only do they show you how to set the expires headers, but all kinds of goodies to make your apache install work really well.  Or you can see the file on their github repo https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess