# HTTP Headers: Controlling Cache and History Mechanism

Tags: http, caching, proxy, history, browser-cache

I'm trying to figure out the best HTTP headers to send for four use cases. I'm hoping to come up with headers that do not depend on user agent / protocol version sniffing but I'll accept that if nothing else fits. All URLs are fetched through fully custom handler so I can select all headers as I like, *this is all about intermediate proxies and user agents*. If possible, this should be compatible with both HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 clients. If multiple solutions exists, the best one will be the shortest one when sent over the wire.

**Static public content**

All "Static public content" is stuff that HTTP is really all about: if the URL is the same, the content is the same. I can do this easily: for example, I put user profile icon into http://domain.com/profiles/xyz/icon/1234abcd where "1234abcd" is the SHA-1 of the file contents of the icon. If I change to icon in the future, I'll create a new URL and and modify all existing referrers that should use the new icon. What are the best headers to declare that this may be cached forever and may be shared? I'm currently thinking something along the lines:

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time + one year>
```

Is this enough to allow caching by user agents and proxies? Do I need `Last-Modified` or `Pragma`?

**Static non-public content**

All "Static non-public content" is stuff that is static but may not be available to everybody. In fact, this content will be available only to selected logged in users (session is kept with session cookie holding session UUID). If the URL is the same, the content is the same. However, the response is not public. An use case could be an image shared to selected friends in a social network service. I'm currently thinking something along the lines:

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time>
Cache-Control: private, max-age=<huge number>, s-maxage=0
```

Is this enough to allow caching by user agents and and disable proxies? Do I need `Pragma`?

**Volatile public content**

All "Volatile public content" is stuff that is volatile and available to everybody. Something like frontpage of http://slashdot.org/ when not logged in. The intent is to allow rapidly updating content in a non-changing URL. *Note that I do NOT want to break the user agent history mechanism* (that is, clicking something from a volatile page and then hitting the back button should not result in fetching the volatile page from the server -- however, clicking a link that goes to front page should fetch the resource from the server). I'm currently thinking something along the lines:

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time>
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
```

Is this enough to prevent caching but to allow history mechanism (back button)? I know that if I send `Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate` I can force reloading but this is not what I want because that will break the back button, too. Do I need `Last-Modified` or `Pragma`?

Even though this is public, it probably does not make sense to allow intermediate proxies to cache this because it's volatile.

**Volatile non-public content**

All "Volatile non-public content" is stuff that is volatile and not available to everybody (private). Something like frontpage of http://slashdot.org/ when you are logged in. The intent is to allow rapidly updating content in a non-changing URL. *Note that I do NOT want to break the user agent history mechanism* (that is, clicking something from a volatile page and then hitting the back button should not result in fetching the volatile page from the server -- however, clicking a link that goes to front page should fetch the resource from the server). I'm currently thinking something along the lines:

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time>
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
```

Is this enough to prevent caching but to allow history mechanism (back button)? Do I need `Pragma`?

---

Things that still need testing with my suggested headers:

- Verify that private content will not be leaked through HTTP/1.0 proxies.
- Verify that caching works correctly in proxies.
- Verify that caching works correctly in user agents.
- Verify that user agent history mechanism works in user agents (all cases).
- Verify that following a link to a volatile page fetches fresh content from the server.
- Verify all the results when using HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: I'm aware about previous similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970938/ideal-http-cache-control-headers-for-different-types-of-resources -- however, that is missing three important pieces of the puzzle: back button behavior, user agent compatibility and HTTP/1.0 proxy support.

Comment: The other often cited source http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/ also suffers from not dealing with real world user agent behavior with back-button and HTTP/1.0 proxy support.

Comment: Here's an article about Cache-Control: http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/ - also missing real world back button behavior, user agent compatibility and HTTP/1.0 proxy support.

Comment: I currently believe that the above Cache-Control headers are correct. Also see my comment at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531801#c24

Comment: Additional links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll answer my own question:

**Static public content**

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time + one year>
```

Rationale: This is compatible with the HTTP/1.0 proxies and RFC 2616 Section 14: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21
The `Last-Modified` header is not needed for correct caching (because conforming user agents follow the `Expires` header) but may be included for the end user consumption. Including the `Last-Modified` header may also decrease the server data transfer in case user hits the Reload/Refresh button. If `Last-Modified` header is added, it should reflect real data instead of something invented up. If you want to decrease server data transfer (in case user hits Reload/Refresh button) and cannot include real `Last-Modified` header, you may add `ETag` header to allow conditional GET (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26). If you already include `Last-Modified` also adding `ETag` is just waste. Note that `Last-Modified` is clearly superior because it's supported by HTTP/1.0 clients and proxies, too. A suitable value for `ETag` in case of dynamic pages is SHA-1 of the contents of the page/resource. Note that using `Last-Modified` or `ETag` will not help with the server load, only with the server outgoing internet pipe / data transfer rate.

**Static non-public content**

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time>
Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=0
Vary: Cookie
```

Rationale: The `Date` and `Expires` headers are for HTTP/1.0 compatibility and because there's no sensible way to specify that the response is private, these headers communicate that the response may not be cached. The `Cache-Control` header tells that this response may be cached by private cache but shared cache may not cache the response. The `s-maxage=0` is added because `private` may not be supported by all proxies that support `Cache-Control` (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3 - I have no idea which proxies are broken). The `max-age` is set to value of `60*60*24*365` (1 year) because the HTTP/1.1 specification does not define any upper limit for this parameter, I guess that this is implementation dependant. The `Expires` headers SHOULD be limited to one year in the future, so using the same logic here should be okay. The `Vary: Cookie` header is required because the session that is used to check if the visitor is allowed to see the content is transferred in a cookie; because the returned response depends on the cookie value the cache may not use cached response if cookie header is changed.

I might personally break the last part. By not including the `Vary: Cookie` header I can improve caching a lot. For example: I have a profile image at `http://example.com/icon/12` which is returned only for selected authenticated users. I have a visitor `X` with session id `5f2` and I allow the image to that user. Visitor `X` logs out and then later logs in again. Now `X` has session id `2e8` stored in his session cookie. If I have `Vary: cookie`, the user agent of `X` cannot use the cached image and is forced to reload this to its cache. Because the content varies by Cookie, a conditional GET with last modification time cannot be used. I haven't tested if using `ETag` could help in this case because in that case, the server response would be the same (match the SHA-1 `ETag` computed from the contents of the response). Be warned that Internet Explorer (at least up to version 9) always forces conditional GET for resources that include `Vary: Cookie` even if suitable response were already in cache (source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx). This is because internal cache implementation of MSIE does not remember which Cookie it sent the first time so it cannot know if the current Cookie is the same one.

However, here's an example of a problem that is caused by dropping the `Vary: Cookie` header to show why this is indeed required for technically correct behavior: see the example above and imagine that after X has logged out, visitor Y logs in with the same user agent (the user agent may have been restarted between X and Y, it does not matter). If Y views a page that includes a link to `http://example.com/icon/12` then Y will see the icon embedded inside the page even though Y wouldn't be able to see the icon if X had not been using the same user agent previously. In my case I don't consider this a big enough problem because Y would be able to access the icon manually by inspecting the user agent cache regardless of possibly added `Vary: Cookie`. However, this issue may prevent Y from noticing that he wouldn't technically have access to this content (this may be important e.g. if Y is co-authoring the content). If the content is considered sensitive, the server must send `no-store` regardless of the problems caused by this `Cache-Control` directive.

Here too, adding `Last-Modified` header will help with users hitting Reload/Refresh button (see discussion above).

**Volatile public content**

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time>
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
Last-Modified: <real-last-modification-time>
```

Rationale: Tell HTTP/1.0 clients and proxies that this response should be considered stale immediately. The `Last-Modified` time is included to allow skipping content data transmission when the resource is accessed again and client supports conditional GET. If the `Last-Modified` cannot be used, `ETag` may be used as a replacement (see discussion above). It's critical to use `Last-Modified` to allow conditional GET with HTTP/1.0 compatible clients.

If the content may be delayed even slightly, then `Expires`, `max-age` and `s-maxage` [sic] should be adjusted suitably. For example, adding 5 seconds to those might help a lot for highly popular site, as suggested by symcbean's answer. Note that unlike conditional GET, increasing the expiry time will decrease server load instead of just decreasing server outgoing data traffic (because the server will see less requests in total).

**Volatile non-public content**

```
Date: <current time>
Expires: <current time>
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
Last-Modified: <real-last-modification-time>
Vary: Cookie
```

Rationale: Tell HTTP/1.0 clients and proxies that this response should be considered stale immediately. The `Last-Modified` time is included to allow skipping content data transmission when the resource is accessed again and client supports conditional GET. If the `Last-Modified` cannot be used, `ETag` may be used as a replacement (see discussion above). It's critical to use `Last-Modified` to allow conditional GET with HTTP/1.0 compatible clients. Also note that `Cache-Control` must not include `no-cache`, `must-revalidate` or `no-store` because using any of these directives will break the back button in at least one user agent. However, if the content the server is transferring contains sensitive material that should not be stored in permanent storage, the `no-store` flag MUST be used regardless of breaking the back button. *Warning:* note that the use of `no-store` cannot prevent sensitive material ending up on the hard disk without encryption if the operating system has swapping enabled and the swap is not encrypted! **Also note that using `no-store` makes very little sense unless the connection is encrypted (HTTPS/SSL).**

Comment: Also note that if you offer downloads of any kind, some user agents might have problems storing the downloaded file if you send `Cache-Control: no-store` combined with `Content-Disposition: attachment`. That combination doesn't logically make any sense, though.

(Also note that some old user agents require spelling `Content-Disposition: atachment` because they have a typo in their source code.)

Answer (score 2):

Mostly OK, however you do need to bear in mind that HTTP/1.0 proxies may cache content served up as

```
Cache-Control: private
```

So you should set an explicit Date-modified header as well as the expires header.

For your 'Static non-public content' you should add a 'Varies: Cookie' header.

For your 'Volatile public content': How fast is it changing? Setting an TTL of +5 seconds may offload a lot of effort from your servers.

For 'Volatile non-public content' you should probably add no-cache,must-revalidate to the Cache-control header.

Pragma headers issued from the server should have no effect on clients nor proxies.

Do test out what happens when your cache expires (IME you can end up with a system even slower than one accessed with no populated cache due to all the conditional requests / 304 responses)

Comment: I'm aware that `Cache-Control: private` is not understood by HTTP/1.0 proxies. That is the reason I put `Date` and `Expires` to the current time. This, if I've understood correctly, should expire the content from HTTP/1.0 proxies immediately. Why do I need explicit `Date-Modified` header? Is it required by some user agents?

Comment: I think that adding `no-cache, must-revalidate` to 'Volatile non-public content' will break the back button in at least Firefox and Internet Explorer. My intent is to keep back button to show actual history (instead of transparent view of server state) if possible at all; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.13 for details.

Comment: I think that the header syntax is `Vary: Cookie`. I  have thought about that but because also the user agent (browser) honors this header it would break user agent caching. For example: I have a profile image at `http://domain.com/icon/12` which is returned only for selected authenticated users. I have a visitor X with session id `5f2` and I allow the image to that user. Visitor X logs out and then later logs in again. Now X has session id `2e8` stored in session cookie. If I have `Vary: cookie`, the user agent of X cannot use the cached image. Technically, `Vary: cookie` would be the correct.