# Reasons why Chrome would make a request twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http

I have the following in my nginx server logs (IPs and some paths changed for the sake of the example):

> 101.101.101.101 - - [15/Apr/2020:14:46:03 +0000] "GET /item/download-file/ready/5e971e290107e HTTP/2.0" 200 142940
>   "https://example.com/referer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
>   x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163
>   Safari/537.36"
>
> 101.101.101.101 - - [15/Apr/2020:14:46:04 +0000] "GET /item/download-file/ready/5e971e290107e HTTP/1.1" 200 5
>   "https://example.com/referer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
>   x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163
>   Safari/537.36"

The trouble is the accessed link is for a non-idempotent resource (it can only be accessed once), thus the client experiences an error.

The links are for a file download, which is accessed by a JavaScript piece involving `window.location.href = "..."`. The response server headers include `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Under what circumstances would Chrome send two requests involving HTTP/2.0 first, then HTTP/1.1 a few moments after? Perhaps there is an extension that could cause this?

Note that I can not reproduce it in any browser I own.

### Update 2:

I have determined it does not just happen in Chrome. Edge 44 came up in logs too. Also, the second request for other instances of this issue did not switch to HTTP/1.1. Instead they are HTTP/2.0.

### Update:

I was asked to provide the response headers for a typical request:

```
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-disposition: attachment; filename=sources.zip
content-length: 8597357
content-transfer-encoding: Binary
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 17:23:44 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx/1.16.1
status: 200
```

Comment: What are the response headers when you do a GET with http2?

Comment: @Jacob I have no reasons to suspect that headers are different for the browser that experiences the issue. For my browser I have added them in the question text.

Comment: Do you see two requests being made from the Network tab in Chrome?

Comment: @Chris, as I said - I can not reproduce the issue with my browsers. This happens on client's Chrome. The question is what could cause this anomaly on a windows chrome install.

Comment: Oh, so an unknown client?

Comment: @Chris let's call it "uncontrolled" rather than unknown, because the user agent says "Chrome 80 on windows"

Comment: Right, I meant if you had direct contact with said client - but I gotcha. What is interesting is that in the http/1.1 case only 5 bytes were sent (instead of 142kB). I'm also curious why the client would experience an error since the http/2.0 request was successful... what kind of error do they experience?

Comment: @Chris it's expected, as it only generates an error (remember, idempotency)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211742/discussion-between-slavic-and-chris).

Comment: You do realise that GETs should be idempotent though right?

Comment: @Caltor, no. GETs "tend" to be idempotent. And it helps if they are. They don't HAVE to be though.

Comment: They do if you want to comply with RFC7231 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-8.1.3. You could be in trouble if a "spider" ever hits your site and decides to visit every GET. Notice though that I said "should" and not "must".

Comment: I would guess the problem is `no-store` combined with downloads. If the UA interprets that literally, it cannot store the downloaded object anywhere. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6519601/334451

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are getting multiple requests (perhaps it is just HTTP 2/1.1 negotiation) but the real answer is that you should make the GET request safe and idempotent and ask the client to send a separate DELETE request. I know this probably isn't the answer you want though.

If you have an unsafe/non-idempotent GET request then you are open to problems if the client makes multiple requests (which it should be free to do) or something like an indexing "spider" or pre-fetch cache ever hits your site and decides to visit every GET endpoint it can find. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1.3 for details of which HTTP methods should and shouldn't be safe and idempotent.

Comment: You are right in that this is not the answer to the question asked. I do not dispute the architecture of the web here, I just say that this is that case when the molds don't quite mold. The resource for which those GET requests are made is a short lived one. Also, the crawler is out of the question as those are "secret" urls.

Comment: @Slavic True, but I think you are asking the wrong question. This strikes me as an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You are asking "why Chrome would make a request twice?" (Y) when I think you should be asking "how can I stop the resource being deleted too early" (X). Your question is likely to end up with a networking rather than programming answer (if you get one at all) and possibly be more suited to a different stackexchange site such as serverfault.com.

Comment: I don't mind it getting a networking answer, that's because I already have an answer to the question you think I should be asking. You are right that this demands more of an empirical answer rather than one based on protocol and theory.

Comment: @Slavic Cool, I'd suggest using Wireshark to capture the network traffic then and post your question on serverfault and/or post your client and server code in your question so someone on here can try and see if there is a problem with your code.