# Is it true that nothing is cached when using https?

Tags: caching, browser, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will web browsers cache content over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https)

[Jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1) most recent [Coding Horror post Breaking the Web Cookie Jar](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/breaking-the-webs-cookie-jar.html) is an eyeopening read for anyone not familiar with how a cookie works. As is typically the case with a post like this the comments are full of [FUD](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FUD). That said, a comment from [Carl Hörberg](http://twitter.com/#!/carlhoerberg) has me concerned:

> Another con with https is that nothing
>   gets cached on the client, so every
>   css, image, js etc has to be fetched
>   on every page load.

A quick Google search yielded no results affirming or contradicting this statement, but that can probably be attributed to poor [Google-fu](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=google-fu). So is it true that nothing gets cached when served via https?

Comment: My Google-fu ("https caching") gives a duplicate with reasonable answers [Will web browsers cache content over https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https)

Answer (score 0):

With https requests, the client typically uses a single connection to the server and pipelines requests, receiving responses in the same order.  In contrast, with http connections, there is one connection per request.  That's the major difference, aside from encryption, of course.  There is nothing preventing a client from using cached responses, although it is possible for a server to return responses on https connections that specify no caching, but I don't see a point in doing that.