# Are https requests cacheable?

Tags: php, caching, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will web browsers cache content over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https)

Are https request cached by the browser. If no how to make them cacheable for some pages like static resources and non cacheable for others.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https). Maybe a bit outdated, but as far as I know still valid...