# how to use mod_headers and mod_expires to cache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires, mod-headers

I want to cache images and other files on my site, so what I did is made sure mod_headers and mod_expires with :-

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -l
```

then edited .htaccess to be:-

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0


# Set up caching on media files for 1 year (forever?)
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A29030400
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files for 1 week
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up 2 Hour caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A9200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|htm)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

But when I browse the site, every time the images reload and take too much time. Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You do not need cache-control public, or most of the other cache-control settings. Pragma is also old and not really needed. You don't really need any of the php|htm portion. I would say scrap everything from the beginning up to the `<files 403.shtml>` part and study (and use) the following code below. I would also recommend reading [Mark Nottingham's  caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)

The following bits of Apache `.htaccess` code were taken from an older version of [html5-boilerplate .htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) and shown here for educational purposes. For your project please use the newest version from the [h5bp/html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) repository.

```
# ######################################################################
# # MEDIA TYPES AND CHARACTER ENCODINGS                                #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Media types                                                        |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with the proper media types (f.k.a. MIME types).
#
# https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

  # Data interchange

    AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
    AddType application/json                            json map topojson
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
    AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
    AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
    AddType application/xml                             rdf xml


  # JavaScript

    # Normalize to standard type.
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2

    AddType application/javascript                      js


  # Manifest files

    # If you are providing a web application manifest file (see
    # the specification: https://w3c.github.io/manifest/), it is
    # recommended that you serve it with the `application/manifest+json`
    # media type.
    #
    # Because the web application manifest file doesn't have its
    # own unique file extension, you can set its media type either
    # by matching:
    #
    # 1) the exact location of the file (this can be done using a
    #    directive such as `<Location>`, but it will NOT work in
    #    the `.htaccess` file, so you will have to do it in the main
    #    server configuration file or inside of a `<VirtualHost>`
    #    container)
    #
    #    e.g.:
    #
    #       <Location "/.well-known/manifest.json">
    #           AddType application/manifest+json               json
    #       </Location>
    #
    # 2) the filename (this can be problematic as you will need to
    #    ensure that you don't have any other file with the same name
    #    as the one you gave to your web application manifest file)
    #
    #    e.g.:
    #
    #       <Files "manifest.json">
    #           AddType application/manifest+json               json
    #       </Files>

    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache


  # Media files

    AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
    AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
    AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

    # Serving `.ico` image files with a different media type
    # prevents Internet Explorer from displaying then as images:
    # https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/37b5fec090d00f38de64b591bcddcb205aadf8ee

    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico


  # Web fonts

    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    # Browsers usually ignore the font media types and simply sniff
    # the bytes to figure out the font type.
    # https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-a-font-type-pattern
    #
    # However, Blink and WebKit based browsers will show a warning
    # in the console if the following font types are served with any
    # other media types.

    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf


  # Other

    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
    AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Reducing MIME type security risks                                  |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Prevent some browsers from MIME-sniffing the response.
#
# This reduces exposure to drive-by download attacks and cross-origin
# data leaks, and should be left uncommented, especially if the server
# is serving user-uploaded content or content that could potentially be
# treated as executable by the browser.
#
# http://www.slideshare.net/hasegawayosuke/owasp-hasegawa
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941.aspx
# https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | ETags                                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Remove `ETags` as resources are sent with far-future expires headers.
#
# https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3

# `FileETag None` doesn't work in all cases.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Expires headers                                                    |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with far-future expires headers.
#
# (!) If you don't control versioning with filename-based
# cache busting, you should consider lowering the cache times
# to something like one week.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media files
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web fonts

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

  # Other
    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

#### Other Boilerplate configurations for various web servers

Server configuration "boilerplates" exist for other HTTP server setups similar to this snippet of Apache configuration and are maintained at https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs

Comment: This looks excellent! However, it should be moved out of the htaccess file. You don't want these processed upon every request.

Comment: @Jumper yes that's true and it is noted in the [full source here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess#L4-L8). Although some folks can't because of restrictive hosting permissions. And FWIW [Simon Greenhill's .htaccess benchmarking](http://simon.net.nz/articles/benchmarking-htaccess-performance/) on the topic revealed in my opinion trivial performance gains versus the ease of maintenance unless the type of site was one with very high traffic.

Comment: In his tutorial, Mark Nottingham says to use https only in the pages where it's needed. In other tutorials, google ones, for example, is suggested to use https everywhere, as much as possible and that it's not true that it affects cache. Also, boilerplate doesn't use Cache-Control at all

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing this. However I have a question, using Expires...it seems that I do not need cache bursting. When I cache a JS file served with 1 day caching, and I change the JS source that is being served, I see that the browser (chrome in  this case) gets the new version, and then caches that one. Is this how it works for all browsers, or do I need to implement cache busting just to be on the safe side?
Edit: I might not be sure of the fact that Chrome reloads..might have been a fluke. So I guess cache busting is the way?

Comment: In the case of caching, it's preferred to attempt to cache your static resources as long as you can. And when you do change things you want to bust other people's (visitors, ISP, googlebot, etc) caches. It's easy enough to bust your own cache manually (ctrl+f5 or ctrl+r I think) but this is not true for the rest of the planet. Hence cache busting tricks exist. Even if you cached one day only, the rest of the folks might not see fresh content for 24 hours. In the case of a javascript change, that could mean a broken app for them.

Comment: @Carlo The tutorial talks about shared caches, for example my ISP uses a shared cache, and how to leverage that cache to maximize the resource to be more cache friendly. If you really don't need HTTPS there is nothing wrong with that. I've seen HTTPS/Google promoting for a number of reasons (seo, ads, privacy, security). Regardless if the resource is on HTTPS [it doesn't prevent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https) the end user from caching it. Also Cache-Control headers will be produced by Apache by all those `ExpiresByType` directives.