# Chrome WON'T clear cache... ctrl + F5 doesn't seem to work either

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I'm working on a web project but I have this really annoying issue with my browser, Google Chrome...
Every time I make changes on my website, my browser won't refresh and clear the cache. It works totally fine in my friend's Chrome browser, but not for me apparently.

As mentioned ctrl + F5 does not work for me. I tried to press F12 (for developer console) and right-click on the refresh icon, and then click "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". Still doesn't work... Actually not true, it worked once - but now it stays the same again... I tried reinstalling chrome too, still didn't work... I tried to clear my whole history including all passwords, cache and so on - but nothing has fixed the issue.

Edited on 02-05-2020:
Some of your answers worked for me, but some time ago I found a Chrome extension that works really well for me and I wanted to share with the community. It is called "Clear Cache" and you can find it here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn/RK%3D2/RS%3DzwqaryCReNAACSfd_oYYPpX0_tw-

Comment: Open developer console -> right click on the refresh icon, and then click "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".
This is new for me and it worked like a charm. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: @JayeshDhandha unfortunately it does not work for all users like a charm. Neither for me this time. Weird, but it's unpredictable when this method works, when it does not O_o

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. What I find is that I need to open up the Chrome developer tools and *then* hit Ctrl + F5. Only then is the cache refreshed.

**Update**

Also, I would recommend that you select "Disable Cache" in the developers tools ("Network" tab).

Comment: Your tip on `disable cache` in `developer tools - network` does it all. Nothing else worked.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to live-back Ctrl+F5? It so programmer-friendly!

Comment: `ctrl+F5` did it for me

Comment: @frazraz this trick didn't work for me don't know why. It was disabled already, as well as CMD+Shift+R or long-click on reload and option "Empty cache and hard reload" - which is ridiculous in my opinion - it does not do what it says...

Comment: Nothing mentioned works, not disable cache tick, no f12 tools opened, nor ctrl - f5, not clicking in chrome and selecting  "Empty cache and hard reload" , just nothing works only refreshing 20 times like mad, for every js change I do, its madness.

Comment: Neither of these works for me. I mean it helps sometimes, but only half of the time.

Comment: this won't work with service workers, and I have seen this problem with some devices, clearing the cache by F12 > ctrl + shift + p > clear site date "may" work

Comment: YES. disable cache in developer tools - network did the job. But, now wondering how to do the same in Chrome on Android!

Comment: Had this issue for years. Try a browser without being logged into a Google account and watch you cache clear.  They are caching in ways they are not telling us.

Comment: disable cache in the network tools was the only way I could get chromium-browser to properly refresh with a CTRL+SHIFT+F5. But it seems that this is only when DevTools is open, so it is not a general solution for getting CTRL+SHIFT+F5 to work as it should.

Answer (score 28):

Also if you right click the reload button there is a Empty Cache and Hard Relaod option

This doesn't work unless you have dev tools open. So you need to first inspect the element,  then right click on the refresh button. Then you have the options of `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`

Comment: wow talk about a hidden feature, I had no idea that was there. Very cool!

Comment: Me too! this was the only thing that worked for me. I think google chrome are happy to push stuff that is untested for example the cache clearing inside developer tools doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share some screenshot - i do not know where to find these options

Comment: @javadba right-click the webpage then select inspect, then right-click the reload/refresh button

Comment: Those options actually started showing up at some point - though they had not originally when doing the same thing.

Comment: The developers of these browsers really need to provide a way to programmatically refresh their browsers (or at least from the command line, eg. delete some file somewhere?). Having to rely on xdotools is really not a solution.

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that worked for me was logging out of my google account. For some reason, being logged in to an account shared between various devices wasn't allowing the cache to purge properly. I tried clearing the browser cache manually, Using a 3rd party cache cleaner, flushing the DNS cache, checking the checkbox in dev tools to ignore cache, using an incognito window. Nothing worked! As soon as I logged out everything purged from the test device properly.

Comment: For the god's sake. This actually worked. How much broken caching is in chrome lol.

Comment: This doesn't help me either.

Answer (score 5):

Hit control + shift + R
for Chrome 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
this is also the Mac key combination
control + shift + F5 doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

In my case, none of the described solutions worked. I have Google Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 64 bit. However, playing around with Chrome controls I found this solution:

1. Click on the 3 vertical dots on the top right corner of the browser
2. Click on "More tools"
3. Click on "Clear Browsing data..."
4. Under the almost invisible "Basic" tab, change "Time range" to "All time"
5. Uncheck "Browsing history", unless you want to clear this data too
6. Uncheck "Cookies and other site data", this one is highly recommended, you probably don't want to lose your login names and passwords for all sites.
7. Check "Cached images and files", this is what we want to clear
8. Click the blue button "Clear data"

That's all.

Comment: This doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is for Internet Explorer, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is for Chrome.

EDIT (Feb 21, 2019): With the more recent Chromes, I've switched to **CTRL-Shift-R** as this seems to be the official - and more reliable - behaviour.

Another answerer pointed out that right-clicking the reload button gave the option, but this no longer seems to be the case (Version 72.0.3626.109).

Comment: You need to have developer tools opened (F12) to have that functionality available.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything, even uninstalling Chrome itself. No luck. It turned out that it's caching using your Google account. I "solved" the issue by appending a random string to my .js filename.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js?r=37173634873"></script>
```

where the number is always different. You can use PHP or the bundler itself

This forces the browser to load the "new" js file

Answer (score 2):

This may be the result of using an [Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). If you have a cache.manifest included in your page via the html tag: `<html manifest="cache.manifest">`, then you have to edit it for the files listed therein to be re-freshed (e.g. consider adding or modifying  a comment like `#v1.0`).

Also ensure the file you want to update is listed in the cache manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The last time F5 and Ctrl-F5 didn't work for me was when I hit the F-lock key (Microsoft keyboard)
It is like Num-Lock but for the function key.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try clearing the cookie data for the relative site in development under Application's: storage/cookies option.

Answer (score 0):

If other advices like Ctrl + F5 and diabling cache still don't work for you, check if Chrome Data Saver is installed and switched on and disable it if it is.

Link to the Chrome Data Saver ext https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac?hl=en (you can see if it is installed at the page and how to switch it off).

Answer (score 0):

For testing and developing purpose **only**, you can make a use of the `.htaccess` file inside your developing root server, it will help you control the caching policy of the browser so you will able to work in non-caching environment.

From Wikipedia ([.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)):

> .htaccess files allow a server to control caching by web browsers and
>   proxies to speed up websites

The `mod_expires` tell the browser that the file is expire so it will go and fetch it again after 1 minute (you can even set it for 0 seconds - the file immediately expires)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 minutes"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 minutes"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 minutes"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 minutes"
</IfModule>
```

see additional [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693181/why-would-anyone-set-apache-mod-expires-parameter-expiresbytype-to-access-plu)

Answer (score 0):

So I also did everything. Cleared the cache, signed out of Chrome. Tried to upload the files using only the FTP etc. etc. etc. Until I realised the reason is server-side caching. I just had to sign into my cPanel and switch Cachewall off.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem countless times while developing software. Even completely clearing the Chrome cache doesn't always work.

The solution for me was to install the Chrome extra: [Classic Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-cache-killer/kkmknnnjliniefekpicbaaobdnjjikfp?hl=en). You click on it in the toolbar, the icon turns green, and as far as I can tell, Chrome caches *nothing*. It automatically turns itself off when you move to another web site.  It has a 5 star rating with over 28,000 reviews.

Once you've loaded a page with Cache Killer on, the old cache files relevant to that page are gone.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on account, need to log out or use chromium for better testing, this piece of code give exact information about held memory:

```
async getCacheStoragesAssetTotalSize() {
        const cacheNames = await caches.keys();

        let total = 0;

        const sizePromises = cacheNames.map(async cacheName => {
            const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
            const keys = await cache.keys();
            let cacheSize = 0;

            await Promise.all(keys.map(async key => {
                const response = await cache.match(key);
                const blob = await response.blob();
                total += blob.size;
                cacheSize += blob.size;
            }));

            console.log(`Cache ${cacheName}: ${cacheSize} bytes`);
        });

        await Promise.all(sizePromises);

        return `Total Cache Storage: ${total / 1e6} MB`;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the copy pasted bit of code, but it won't help solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

Open Chrome Developer Tools By pressing F12 Then Application > LocalStorage and Click the right mouse button and clear. Simply you need to clear the localstorage. You can also do the same thing by using any chrome extension

[image]

Answer (score -6):

In Mac is as simple of shift + cmd + R.
I can imaging in windows is similar as shift + control + R

Life is easy do not complicate.