# Chrome won't clear cache (ctrl+F5, shift+F5 (also with debug console opened) does not work)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, caching, web

I am working on my website, but Chrome just decided to not clear my cache no matter what I do.

If I open the file (CSS and JS) on new tab, I can clearly see the new updated version is being loaded, but chrome itself does not use those files on my website.

I tried F5, CTRL+F5, SHIFT+F5, F12 + Empty Cache and Hard Reload, F12 and then CTRL+F5 (and also SHIFT+F5). I had this issue before and I tried removing it from local storage, deleting local storage file, uninstalling chrome and clearing all data that were not deleted.

**Nothing works!**

As I told, I had this issue before, and what I did was tenaming the file I edited. But I wont just keep renaming my files which I edit (or even adding a version query strings to them).

When I try Device mode (mobile emulation option in debug console on Chrome), it actually uses the new version of files there. But when I disable it, it goes back to old version in cache.

Any ideas? Its extremly annyoing and preventing me to work on my website, as any changes I do to CSS and JS are just being ignored.

Ps.: I know there is this question: [Chrome WON'T clear cache... ctrl + F5 doesn't seem to work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958420/chrome-wont-clear-cache-ctrl-f5-doesnt-seem-to-work-either), but the accepted answer its not working at all for me and your FAQ has nothing like: "What to do if you have same question that was once answered but answer does not work for you...".

Thanks.

Comment: Well, AFAIK if you surf incognito then cache is not stored or loaded so that can work as well. Also, restting chrome settings will do the trick, if not i'm afraid there is something messing up with your system.

Comment: Give a try for CTRL+SHIFT+R ?
[Chrome Keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts)

Comment: as a workaround `<script src="file.js?v=1">` - when you want to force new content, increase the value of v - saves you from renaming files, but it is a pain in the butt - the fact that uninstalling chrome didn't make a difference, though, is extremely strange - what server software are you using?

Comment: Incognito does not work, CTRL+SHIFT+R did not work either. And as I told, I don't want to use queries with versions every time I change position of one div by couple pixels... Server is from company websupport.sk (I never had problems with them). I am also using Cloudflare, but I had this problem just once before and I am using clouflare for more than year (almost two). I have no idea whats going on, why is this happening and why if I use mobile emulation it loads the propper file versions.

Comment: Ok, so after some time its working in incognito mode, but still not it normal one. Damn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after couple hours, what actually worked was to go to:

Resources -> local Storage -> https://rankpoll.me -> remove everything -> Right click on refresh button -> select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" -> voila

Thing is, that was not working couple hours before and also last time I had this problem, so IDK whats going on with my chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Data Saver extension was causing the problem.

Data saver extension can also prevent the changes to be applied. It minifies files to improve the performance.