# In Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 how do I reduce margin/padding between <li> and the 'shorten" JS plugin

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 with CSS (and do not wish to use SASS). I'm running Windows 7. I'm using Jquery Shorten to display a list of languages https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten

I am trying to reduce the space between the last li with "Azerbaijani transcription and translation" and the following "more".
I unsuccessfully tried to target to reduce the margin and padding top or bottom....

See screenshot: 
[image: screenshot of "more"]

My html code and css are as follows

```css
.reducetop {
  padding-top: 1.75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;

}

.reducebottom {
  padding-bottom: 5.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 5.75rem;
}

.reducetop ul {
  padding-top: 1.75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;

}

.reducebottom ul {
  padding-bottom: 5.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 5.75rem;
}


ul.reducetop {
  padding-top: 1.75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;

}

ul.reducebottom {
  padding-bottom: 5.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 5.75rem;
}

.reducetop ul li {
  padding-top: -1.75rem;
  margin-top: -1.75rem;

}

.reducebottom ul li {
  padding-bottom: -5.75rem;
  margin-bottom: -5.75rem;
}

li.reducemargin{
margin: 0px;
}

ul.reducemargin { 
  margin:-20px;
}

.reducemargin ul { 
  margin:-20px;
}

.reducemargin ul li { 
  margin:-20px;
}

ul.noindent {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.imagelist li{
            Padding:0;
            margin:0;
}
```

```html
      <div class="row"> 
         <div class="small-12 medium-12 columns">
          <h4>more languages</h4> 

          <p>over the years we've worked on audio and video transcription projects involving many other languages including:</p>

            <div class="medium-4 columns">
            <div class="reducetop reducemargin imagelist">
            <ul class="noindent imagelist">
              <li>Albanian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Amharic transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Arakanese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Armenian transcription and translation</li>
              <li class="reducemargin noindent imagelist">Azerbaijani transcription and translation</li>           
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="reducetop reducemargin">
          <ul class="comment-small reducemargin noindent imagelist">
              <li>Aymara transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Belarusan transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Bengali transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Bhilali transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Burmese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Cambodian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Caqchiquel transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Chechen transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Creole transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Dari transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Dinka transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Faroese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Farsi transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Flemish transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Fulani transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Georgian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Uzbek transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Greenlandic transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Guarani transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Gujerati transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Hassaniya transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Icelandic transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Inuktitut transcription and translation</li>
           </ul> 
           </div>

         </div> 

          <div class="medium-4 columns comment">
          <ul>
              <li>Albanian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Amharic transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Arakanese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Armenian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Azerbaijani transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Aymara transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Belarusan transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Bengali transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Bhilali transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Burmese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Cambodian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Caqchiquel transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Chechen transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Creole transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Dari transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Dinka transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Faroese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Farsi transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Flemish transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Fulani transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Georgian transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Uzbek transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Greenlandic transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Guarani transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Gujerati transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Hassaniya transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Icelandic transcription and translation</li>
              <li>Inuktitut transcription and translation</li>
           </ul> 

         </div> 
          </div>

          </div>
```

:

This is the shorten plugin script I have in my html.

```
<script language="javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$(".comment").shorten();

$(".comment-small").shorten({
  showChars: 10,
  moreText: 'more',
  lessText: 'less',
  ellipsesText: '...',
});

$(".comment-list").shorten({
  showChars: 10,
  moreText: 'more',
  lessText: 'less',
  ellipsesText: '...',
});

$(".comment-test").shorten({showChars: 30});
```

});

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of bits of code that are redundant in your question above (I'm guessing attached to elsewhere in your site)

e.g.

```
ul.reducetop {
  padding-top: 1.75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;

}
```

Where the class `reducetop` is applied to a `div` (in your shown code) and some of the jQuery references elements that don't exist in the HTML (e.g. `$(".comment-test").shorten({showChars: 30});` etc.

So to help me answer your question I have trimmed the CSS, JS and HTML not related to your problem with the gap in a particular column.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-12 columns">
    <h4>more languages</h4>
    <p>over the years we've worked on audio and video transcription projects involving many other languages including:</p>
    <div class="medium-6 columns end">
      <div class="">
        <ul class="noindent imagelist">
          <li>Albanian transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Amharic transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Arakanese transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Armenian transcription and translation</li>
          <li class="">Azerbaijani transcription and translation</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="comment-small noindent imagelist">
          <li>Aymara transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Belarusan transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Bengali transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Bhilali transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Burmese transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Cambodian transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Caqchiquel transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Chechen transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Creole transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Dari transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Dinka transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Faroese transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Farsi transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Flemish transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Fulani transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Georgian transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Uzbek transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Greenlandic transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Guarani transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Gujerati transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Hassaniya transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Icelandic transcription and translation</li>
          <li>Inuktitut transcription and translation</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Just one column, some classes removed and one class applied to relevant `ul`s)

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".comment-small").shorten({
    showChars: 10,
    moreText: 'more',
    lessText: 'less',
    ellipsesText: '...',
  });
}).foundation();
```

(Same, but with the Foundation initialisation call at the end and cut to only the one list to be "shortened")

CSS

```
ul.noindent {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.imagelist {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.shortcontent,
.morelink {
  float: left;
}
```

So basically: If you remove all the css related to padding or margins applied to elements which are parents and children of the lists, then pick a class for your `ul` elements that will govern the spacing (I've reused your `imagelist` class for the example) you can set the margin and padding to 0 (or whatever you require).

Then to reduce the (perceived) gap further (it is already 0) you can stack the ellipsis and "more" `span` on the same line using the classes that jQuery.Shortening adds to created elements:

```
.shortcontent,
.morelink {
  float: left;
}
```

You could also pad the `.shortcontent` (ellipsis) to create a horizontal gap between the elements if required.

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/0dvf2gzk/

Comment: Thanks so much but I can't get it to work with my js files which seem different than what you pasted. I forked your fiiddle and updated using my original js file per https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/ky6tneat/ and to show you the other custom.js file see https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/7dsaucqj/

Comment: The pasted code is from the Shorten minified JS file on Github. Your fork works for me though?

Comment: sorry I had not updated please see the jquery.shorten.js which does not work in the fiddle in: https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/ky6tneat/1/

Comment: You are loading the plugin, but not actually using it. If you put the "call" to the plugin after the plugin code `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".comment-small").shorten({
    showChars: 10,
    moreText: 'more',
    lessText: 'less',
    ellipsesText: '...',
  });
}).foundation();` (as above) It will work as expected.

Comment: Tx it works perfectly in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/ky6tneat/5/. However not in the live site: I believe narrowed down the issue to "margin-bottom" which is not picking up the css class from the <ul> https://www.dropbox.com/s/cojm8wi3k86sfqo/Screenshot%202017-01-23%2012.07.53.png?dl=0 - been trying for over an hour and can't pin point what I'm doing wrong... - the url is http://iprobesolutions.com/transcription-services/ if helpful

Comment: Just had a peek and it looks like you've solved it by zeroing the margins on `ul.no-indent` :-)

Comment: the fiddle is working but the website is not... ul.noindent is not being affecting anything...would you mind taking a look at the site url from my previous message ?

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding what you are aiming to achieve. I have visited your link and the site seems identical to the fiddle in form and function: https://i.imgsafe.org/72b5f4b056.png

Comment: Could you look using Chrome ? There it shows with too much space: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cojm8wi3k86sfqo/Screenshot%202017-01-23%2012.07.53.png?dl=0. I now checked in IE 11 and there it does indeed look fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133904/discussion-between-tymothytym-and-julie-s).

Answer (score 0):

As @tymothytym clarified in chat part of the issue I was having was due to 
the Chrome cache bug - per his suggestion I followed the directions from [Chrome WON'T clear cache... ctrl + F5 doesn't seem to work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958420/chrome-wont-clear-cache-ctrl-f5-doesnt-seem-to-work-either)