# Chrome Refuses to Clear Javascript Cache (Even After Hard Reload and Manual Cache Clear)

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

Like the title says, Google Chrome refuses to load newer versions of a Javascript file.

I've tried:

- Ctrl + F5
- Dev Console > Network Tab > Disable Cache
- Disable Cache, Then With Dev Console Still Open Right Click Refresh > Empty Cache and Hard Reload
- Disable Cache, Then With Dev Console Still Open Ctrl + F5
- Chrome Settings > Manually Delete All Cache From Beginning Of Time, Then Ctrl + F5

Basically everything listed here: [Chrome WON'T clear cache... ctrl + F5 doesn't seem to work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958420/chrome-wont-clear-cache-ctrl-f5-doesnt-seem-to-work-either)

None of this worked. The sources panel still shows that the old Javascript file was being loaded. The absolutely mind-boggling thing is that when I right click the file in the sources panel and then select open in new tab, the **updated** file opens in a new tab, but then refreshing the page **still** brings up the old file in the sources panel of dev console.

The *only* thing that has gotten Chrome to work for me is to manually append ? and a random number at the end of the file name. That seems to force Chrome to actually load the new file. As of now, I've been using PHP to add a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js<?php echo '?' . rand(); ?>"></script>
```

in order to get anything to load correctly in Chrome, but this seems like a terrible solution.

My question is, How do I get Chrome to actually reload Javascript files from the server instead of the cache?

Comment: Can you show us actual file HTTP requests? You can use Chrome DevTools [Copy All as HAR](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy) feature, [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or any other web development tool.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, even clearing from the application tab, there is not Cache API from a service worker or any other cache besides standard browser cache. It does show as updated in a private window and eventually after 30 minutes or so clears on it's own.

Comment: If I view the file directly it does not show as updated, I need to append a cache buster parameter like ?sdfsdf, then I see the updated file.

Comment: can you try this echo "<script>localStorage.clear();</script>"; on the top of file;

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried completely wiping your cache ?

C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem at server end by adding to the response header:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Also if you want to use Ctrl+F5, do this after opening the developer console - it should work.
Make sure to check 'disable cache' in network tab in the developer console.

Answer (score -2):

It is incredibly annoying.  You can force a reload by opening the inspect window in Chrome and selecting Network and Disable cache.

Other than that Ctrl+F5 doesn't work.