# Clear browser cache for CORS

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, cache-invalidation

I need to clear the cache for one file in Chrome.

I was setting up loading a font from my own CDN, and added the `cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable` header. However, I did not setup CORS correctly, so I got a CORS error. Now, that CORS error is fixed, but Chrome is still serving the old request because of the cache control header.

Note: I only need to clear the cache this one time. I want the font to be immutable in the future.

#### Things I've tried

- Clear recent browser cache from settings
- In Devtools > Network, select "Disable cache"
- In Devtools > Network, right-click the network request and select "Clear from cache"
- Hard reload with ⌘⇧R (on a Mac)
- Long-click the refresh button in the upper left and select "Empty cache and hard reload" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/11506995)

And I can confirm that the CORS error for two reasons:

- Now works in Safari (didn't before)
- Running `curl -IL -X'GET' -H'Origin: http://localhost:3000' https:example.com/file` returns the correct CORS headers

#### Related posts

- [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)
- [How to force Chrome browser to reload .css file while debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562384/how-to-force-chrome-browser-to-reload-css-file-while-debugging-in-visual-studio)
- [Chrome WON'T clear cache... ctrl + F5 doesn't seem to work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958420/chrome-wont-clear-cache-ctrl-f5-doesnt-seem-to-work-either)

Comment: I thought I was having the same issue as you, but it turns out that it was the HTTPS Everywhere browser extension injecting the `upgrade-insecure-requests` header.

Comment: I thought I was having the same issue as you but in my case I had two things setting CORS headers - my own settings and, unbeknown to me, the WordPress REST API - what I thought was my old setting in .htaccess was in fact WordPress setting them. It didn't work for me because I had two conflicting sets.