# Cache everything but HTML page (partial caching)

Tags: html, caching, resources, http-caching

Right now I am using a mix of HTTP headers and meta tags to disable the caching of my whole page. For slow connections it's just a nightmare.

Now my question:
Is it possible to partially disable caching? E.g. I would like to disable caching for the HTML page, but still cache all scripts, stylesheets, images, etc...

Comment: You will need to set different headers for the HTML page. If you are using a server such as nginx, you can do this via MIME type. What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache, and it seems like there are some useful configuration possibilities like mod_expires and the "Header set"-option. Can I achieve my aim?

Comment: It is certainly possible; if it weren't the web would be in quite a terrible state. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933012) for methods and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Leave scripts, stylesheets and images as static files and let the webserver handle them. The server will make them cacheable by default, unless you go out of your way to configure it otherwise.

Use PHP or similar to add the appropriate HTTP headers to your HTML page.

If your HTML page is a static file, check out [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html).