# Caching and HTTPS

Tags: caching, http-status-code-301, browser-cache

I've noticed something interesting while monitoring the network communications between my browser and server. It has something to do with caching.

Say I have a CSS file http://domain.com/main.css (used in unsecured pages), which can also be accessed via https://domain.com/main.css (used in secured pages).

1. When I first load an unsecured page, the CSS file gets a `200 OK`. When I reload the page (or go to another unsecured page), I get a `304 Not Modified`.
2. When I go to a secured page for the first time, the CSS file from the https source gets a `200 OK`. And when I reload the page (or go to another secured page, I get a `304 Not Modifie`.
3. When I return to the unsecured page, the CSS file still gets a `304 Not Modified`.
4. When I return to the secured page, the CSS file gets a `200 OK`. **What happened to the cached copy? How can I make it cached?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https) might answer your question. It might be the case that your website defines this resource as non cacheble by defining this :

```
Cache-Control   private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

for example ( when accessing https://www.google.com/ncr) causing your browser not to cache it. Do you have Fire-bug\Fiddler or anything similar to view the response headers?

Comment: My .htaccess has this: `ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"` and my response headers has the expiration as: `Expires:Thu, 22 Sep 2022 22:25:51 GMT`. Since it is redundant to specify Expires and Cache-Control, I only use Expires.

Comment: Can you please paste the whole header (Response & Request)?

Comment: Never mind. I was reading Firebug incorrectly. It was saying 200 OK even though it got the resource from cache.