# Login page uses SSL, unencrypted pages don't see encrypted session cookie (Grails, Acegi)

Tags: session, grails, ssl, cookies, spring-security

Setup: Grails 1.1, Acegi/Spring Security plug-in

I want users to log in over SSL, so I have '/login/**' in my channelConfig.secure[] list, but almost everything else is in channelConfig.insecure[]. Every request for /login gets redirected to https:// and every other request is redirected to http://.

My problem is that the login process sets the cookie to "Send over encrypted connections only," so when the login page redirects to /home, the home page doesn't see the cookie and redirects me back to the landing page. When I try to log in again, the login page sees the cookie and redirects me...etc.

I hunted through [this page about SecurityConfig](http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Customizing+with+SecurityConfig) to see if there is an option to allow cookies created over SSL to be read over unencrypted HTTP, but I found nothing. Is there some option I can set to make my login cookie available to my unencrypted controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a vulnerability.

Any man-in-the-middle that can see the session cookie would be able to make requests as the user. This is almost as bad as the password being intercepted. The man-in-the-middle wouldn't be able to establish new sessions on his own, but he would be able to do anything the user can do once a user logs in.

---

Using SSL does a lot more than simply hiding the user name and password at login.

First, it provides confidentiality for all messages between the client and server. It's easy to recognize the password as sensitive data, but it might not be as obvious which application features use sensitive data as well. Protecting any user input and dynamically generated content is safer and easier than trying to carefully evaluate the privacy issues of each data field used in your application. Static content such as images, help pages, etc., probably isn't as sensitive, but by analyzing requests for that content, an attacker might get a good idea of what a user is doing on the site.

Second, SSL provides integrity for every request. This prevents an attacker from modifying or appending their own nefarious input to user requests, or modifying the results produced by the server.

Comment: So having the login page as the only encrypted page is just as bad as no encryption at all?

Is there any way to avoid having passwords sent in plain text but not have to encrypt every page? If not, I'll have to change my approach.

Comment: Almost. You aren't revealing the password, which might spare the user some trouble if they use the same password on other sites, but your site is completely vulnerable. I updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Our main reason for using unencrypted connections was performance, but after reading another question about HTTP vs HTTPS performance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance), I think we won't take a major speed it from it, since almost all of our content is dynamic.

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548029/how-much-overhead-does-ssl-impose/548042#548042 One thing I tried point out there is that SSL has its own "session" that can improve performance even more if it is turned on.

Comment: I was wondering about this - people always recommend using ssl for logging in, but it's no good unless everything is encrypted.