# Loading HTTPS content on HTTP pages

Tags: security, http, https, protocols

Can non-secure pages (HTTP) load secure content (HTTPS) without any unwanted side effect (eg: browser alerts, failed load, etc)?

I know secure (HTTPS) pages shouldn't load non-secure (HTTP) content and that protocol-less URLs can help alleviate this problem. I would like to know if the opposite is also true.

Thanks,
Omar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem would be if the User Agent doesn't support HTTPS, otherwise loading secure content on a non-secure page should work and shouldn't generate warnings.

Regarding whether it *SHOULD* be done, read: [Is there any reason not to serve https content on a page served over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641096/is-there-any-reason-not-to-serve-https-content-on-a-page-served-over-http)