# Secure content in non secure page

Tags: html, security, http, https

Are there any drawbacks/issues when we use secure content in a nonsecure page ? I have an image which is rendered from a third party which is needed across both secure and nonsecure pages. What are the alternate options if this practice is not recommended? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The is no drawback apart from speed.

However, if you use http content on https page your user will have a security warning about the page containing unsecure content.

Also duplicate of: [Is there any reason not to serve https content on a page served over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641096/is-there-any-reason-not-to-serve-https-content-on-a-page-served-over-http)