# Does encrypted SMTP on port 465 slower than normal SMTP

Tags: ssl, smtp

I'm sending emails via encrypted SMTP on port 465, Is it slower than unsecured SMTP on port 25.

Is there any benchmark or valid comprising?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548029/how-much-overhead-does-ssl-impose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SSL will obviously make it slower as it adds computational overhead and will not reduce your data size either (network traffic).

You may also add STARTTLS to the bunch which further adds an TLS initiation phase.

If you are interested in actual numbers then check the link provided by Gryphius.