# Performance Implications when sending large files via HTTPS

Tags: https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP vs HTTPS performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance)

When sending larger files (e.g. 10-15 MB)  over HTTPS (as opposed to HTTP) what are the performance implications (if any)? (the files are CSVs) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS is more CPU intensive than HTTP. A good way to find out if that is OK or not in your usage scenario is to test and measure.

Generally speaking, I'd say that neither is the right tool for the job. One potential problem is that not all server support resume of interrupted transfers. Also, HTTPS normally doesn't do any compression.

You'll find a good answer in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this answer...

[HTTP vs HTTPS performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance)

... and then measure the performance. It should be very simple to test this and see what the performance characteristics are in your particular setup.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously [HTTP vs HTTPS performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance) has lots of details, but remember that a lot of the cost of SSL is in the session setup, so the encryption for the transfer will be less costly (relatively) for a large transfer.