# How do I increase the performance of HttpWebResponse on HTTPS Requests?

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am building an application that highly relies on the loading speed of a web page.

I am not getting any good results with HttpWebResponse on C#. I am getting better results with internet browsers like Chrome and IE

**Here are the stats that i collected:**

HttpWebResponse (C#) = 17 Seconds / 20 Requests

Javascript/iFrame on Chrome = 9 seconds / 20 requests

Javascript/iFrame on IE = 11 seconds / 20 requests

**Question #1**
Is there anything i can do, to optimize my code for better performance?

**Question #2**
I can click start button twice and open two connections, so that i can get on par with browser performance. This works great, however the website i send a request to has a limit. If i send a new request before the other one is completed, it blocks my connection for 10 minutes. Is there a way i can prevent this?

My Thread:

```
void DomainThreadNamecheapStart()
{
    while (stop == false)
    {
        foreach (string FromDomainList in DomainList.Lines)
        {
            if (FromDomainList.Length > 1)
            {
                // I removed my api parameters from the string
                string namecheapapi = "https://api.namecheap.com/foo" + FromDomainList + "bar";

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(namecheapapi);
                request.Proxy = null;
                request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                status.Text = FromDomainList + "\n" + sr.ReadToEnd();

                sr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stop = false;
    Thread DomainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DomainThreadNamecheapStart));
    DomainThread.Start();
}
```

***My Old Question:***
[How do I increase the performance of HttpWebResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071945/how-do-i-increase-the-performance-of-httpwebresponse)

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Comment: Not much, I added more details and asked one more thing. I also made it clear that the issue was using HTTPS. I apologize if it looks the same, but after reading and trying a lot of possible solutions, i got tired of trying and i thought i could ask it again making it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a thread every time the button is pressed. Creating a thread is expensive and takes time by itself. Try using a thread from an existing thread pool (try `QueueUserWorkItem`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Even better, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx and use the new Async methods and do an await to see if you get better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, I am new to C# so you could be right. I will take a look and see if it helps. I press the button only once, i am not sure if that matters.