# node user authentication with cookie

Tags: node.js, authentication, session-cookies, passport.js

I am going to write a server api that responsible for user authentication. From my limit knowledge and understanding, when a user login with username and password, session will be created and auth cookie with username will save into cookie. When the user request for the next page, the user information in the cookie will send to server and server will recognize it. so my question is what if another person manually copy the existing cookie info and create the same cookie in a browser of another computer? Will it skip the login stage? Can anyone explain in details how to prevent this in details? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will most likely skip the login stage. What you describe is a form of session hijacking, or cookie hijacking. Using cookies over unencrypted connection (ie. HTTP instead of HTTPS) is not a secure solution because anyone can steal and use the same cookie and this is usually enough to get full access with no need to authenticate. (It can be - though it usually isn't - made harder to exploit but not impossible.)

Soon there will be no reason not to use HTTPS (see [my answer to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance/27241472#27241472) for details).

In addition to making sure that no one can read the cookie (using HTTPS and [HttpOnly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie)) you also have to make sure that no one can guess the session ID (eg. it cannot be a sequential or small number or anything like that).

See also:

- [Session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) on Wikipedia
- [Session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack) on OWASP
- [Session fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) on Wikipedia
- [Session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) on OWASP
- [Session riding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_riding) (XSRF, CSRF)