# JAVA: What's the fastest and best way to get a response code from HTTPS URL?

Tags: java, url, https

```
    private int getResponse(String url) throws Exception {

    try {
       URL check = new URL(url);
       HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)check.openConnection();
       connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
       connection.connect();

       return(connection.getResponseCode());

    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
           return getResponse(url);
    }

}
```

Is there a faster way to get the response code from a URL than HttpsURLConnection?

I tried HeadMethod from the HTTP Client Commons but that's not that much faster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot magically make the server faster.

Comment: `connection.setRequestMethod("GET")` and `connection.connect()` are both redundant. Don't use recursion as an iteration technique.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect that differences will be absolutely minimal, when compared to normal internet delays and the network stack that Java itself is using (provided by the underlying OS).

While making 1 request will incur in roughly the same overhead regardless of library (as long as it is not completely broken; both Apache Commons and JDK are ok), if you are going to make multiple requests, there are several things that will dramatically improve performance:

- If you need to complete several requests as soon as possible, and do not need each one to complete before you can start others, then go parallel. A useful pointer may be https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client (part of Project Grizzly; uses NIO for non-blocking, highly scalable communication)
- If you will perform additional requests from the same site, then you will see a dramatic performance improvement (> 2x) if you use the keep-alive header and reuse the same connection for several requests. This is due to the high setup costs of HTTPS connections. More information at [HTTP vs HTTPS performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance) (and a nice diagram [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITAME/SC32-1363-00/en_US/HTML/ss7aumst18.htm)). First-time HTTPS requests need 2 round-trips to negotiate encryption before any data is exchanged; further requests can avoid the handshake.