# Is there any reason not to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, security, https

I just wrote a rule in my .htaccess to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. It seems pretty common, but I was just wondering if that could have any negative effect. As far as I know it actually helps as far as SEO is concerned. Is there any scenario where a user wants non secure access, can't access a secured site or anything like that? Or am I missing something else besides SEO and accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/570288/is-it-bad-to-redirect-http-to-https) about this on Server Fault. The consensus appears to be that this is a good idea.

This [blog post](https://moz.com/blog/seo-tips-https-ssl) covers some of the drawbacks. There's also this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/downsides-to-using-https) from the Information Security Stack Exchange.

If you use AdSense, you might see a [decrease](https://www.seroundtable.com/https-google-adsense-19035.html) in earnings due to the forced SSL compliance.

Your site may perform [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance) than it would using HTTP.