# JsFiddle Bonescript Fail After Fork

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, beagleboneblack

I found a public fiddle that I am trying to modify for my purposes. It reads analog values from a BeagleBone and displays them on the screen. It works well and updates the values when I run it from the original author's fiddle. But when I fork the fiddle and access it from my dashboard though, it does not appear to work. The values do not update.

I have confirmed it is running from my beaglebone, as it stops updating when I remove power. I also thought it might be a port conflict or something, the two fiddles fighting for access, but that does not seem to be the case. I disproved this by opening multiple instances of the original author's fiddle and they all update in unison, I can even modify them without causing a problem, but nothing works when saved in my dashboard.

... I don't get it, does some weird setting change occur when I fork the file?

HTML:

```
<h1>BoneScript Analog Value Monitor</h1>

<p>AIN0 = <span id="ain0"></span> </p> 
<p>AIN1 = <span id="ain1"></span> </p> 
<p>AIN2 = <span id="ain2"></span> </p> 
<p>AIN3 = <span id="ain3"></span> </p> 
<p>AIN4 = <span id="ain4"></span> </p> 
<p>AIN5 = <span id="ain5"></span> </p> 
<p>AIN6 = <span id="ain6"></span> </p>
```

Javascript:

```
setTargetAddress('beaglebone.local', {
initialized: run
});
setTargetAddress('192.168.7.2', {
    initialized: run
});

// The demo BoneScript application within the 'run()' function
function run() {
    /*
     * Setup
     */
    var b = require('bonescript');
    var ain = [];

    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < b.bone.pinIndex.length; i++) {
            if (b.bone.pinIndex[i].name == 'AIN' + j) {
                ain[j] = b.bone.pinIndex[i].key;
            }
        }
    }

    var index = 0;
    doRead();

    function doRead() {
        b.analogRead(ain[index], onRead);
    }

    function onRead(x) {
        try {
            $('#ain' + index).html(x.value.toFixed(3));
        } catch (ex) {
            $('#ain' + index).html('XXXXX');
        }
        index++;
        if (index > 6) {
            index = 0;
            setTimeout(doRead, 100);
        } else {
            doRead();
        }
    }
}
```

Original Author's Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkridner/gC6um/

My forked Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kjorkis/97002L1m/

Answer (score 0):

So I bounced my face off the desk til the desk started complaining.

Then I noticed something strange. It turns out that JSFiddle.net will use a secured connection when accessing your OWN fiddles, but not others... that means the URL for my fiddle was 'https://' instead of 'http://'.

Reading the attached link explained the time lag for HTTPS connections, and considering the beaglebone is sending several small packets of data, to and from JSFiddle, it did not play nice.

HTTP vs HTTPS: [HTTP vs HTTPS performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance)